# postgresql - locate random row inbetween two specific rows which follow a pattern

Tags: postgresql

Scratching my head trying to get this to work. I have a historic table which has multiple rows (actions) for an account. I know the pattern for before and after a specific action and would like a query to locate the action inbetween for all accounts on that table. Trouble is everything I've tried can locate the actions I want to use as a guide (before and after) but not the one in the middle.

For instance, here is a table example to help explain the scenario:

```
|action id |     comment     |  timestamp   |
|----------|-----------------|--------------|
|   0110   | random comment  |  timestamp 1 |
|   0117   | text pattern 1  |  timestamp 2 | 
|   0129   | RANDOM COMMENT  |  timestamp 3 |
|   0130   | text pattern 2  |  timestamp 4 |
|   0136   | random comment  |  timestamp 5 |
|   etc..  |                 |              |
```

So as you can see the only consistent pattern I have to work with is the text pattern before and after the target row (id 129). I included the timestamps as I thought perhaps it might be something that could perhaps be used? There are other columns on the table but they are essentially random and not much use for purposes of this query.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance for any advice, it's very much appreciated.

Code I used which did not work:

```
select distinct ht.accountid, ht.id, ht.comment
  from historic_table ht 
 where ht.id > (select MAX(ht1.id) from historic_table ht1 where ht1.accountid = ht.accountid and ht1.comment ilike '%comment pattern 1%')
   and ht.id < (select MAX(ht2.id) from historic_table ht2 where ht2.accountid = ht.accountid and ht2.comment ilike '%comment pattern 2%')
 limit 10
```

And here is an example of the output I'm looking to select. In yellow are the rows before and after with the distinct text patterns. In green I have highlighted all the rows I'd like to see in the output. I included only 2 examples one with 1 target row and another with multiple target rows. I hope this helps clarify:

[image]

Comment: 1) Find the ids for the two patterns. 2) find the records with the ids in between these ids. (or if you want order on timestamp: use the timestamps)

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick response. Would you be able to express with with some pseudo code on postgresql? I've tried to do this and so far my attempts were futile. On my last attempt I actually crashed my company's database which went down for 15 mins so I thought best ask on here before I do something like that again. I'll update my question with the code I used if that helps.

Comment: please do so...

Comment: @VaoTsun Updated with code now, thanks again for taking a look at this.

Comment: Please define `between`. Do you mean ids between those of the records with the patterns, or timestamps between those of the records with the patterns? And `... ilike '%comment pattern 1%')`will always be slow.

Comment: also please show wanted result as data set

Comment: Extra questions: 1) is there **only one** record in between? 2) is there **only one** such a sequence of records in the entire table ?

Comment: @wildplasser-  Sure thanks, so for the example above I need to select only row with action id 129 (all columns). There might be occasions where there are multiple rows in between, and if possible I would like to select all of those. I'll also update with a data set example as asked by Vao, for both scenarios to try and help explain better.

Comment: @wildplasser - 1) Not always, I'd like the query to accommodate both scenarios if possible. 2) No there would be multiple accounts with this sequence and I'd like the output to show them all. I'm creating a demo data set now and will update the question shortly as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the results needed, albeit with a compromised output format by using string_agg to include all action ids and comments inbetween the two specified text patterns for all accounts. Posted it below just in case anybody else could make use of it:

```
  select ht.accountid
        ,string_agg(ht.id::text, ', ') as actions_ids
        ,string_agg(ht.comment, ', ') as comments
    from historic_table ht 
   where ht.timestamp >= '2017-02-01'
     and ht.timestamp <  '2017-03-01'
     and ht.id > (select max(ht1.id) from historic_table ht1 where ht1.accountid = ht.accountid and ht1.comment ilike '%comment pattern 1%')
     and ht.id < (select max(ht2.id) from historic_table ht2 where ht2.accountid = ht.accountid and ht2.comment ilike '%comment pattern 2%')
group by ht.accountid
order by 1
```

Specifically I had to remove the distinct (which I didn't need anyway) and this was the culprit for causing the crash when I had run it before (the table was so large with many custom comments the distinct was trying to sort/unique the entire result set and overloaded the data stored in pg_temp). By adding a timestamp filter and dropping the distinct it actually runs pretty fast now.

Answer (score 1):

This not perfect, not optimal, but it appears to work. The CTE guarantees that the actionhistory table is only scanned once, but it will still be a sequential scan, because of the `ILIKE '% zzz%'` .

If the history is relatively stable, I would probably save the ids of the start/stop records in a (temp) table instead of a CTE.

**NOTE**: this solution *assumes* that the records are *properly ordered* (every start pattern has **exactly one** matching stop pattern, and that they do not *nest*)

---

```
CREATE TABLE zaction(
        id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , zcomment text
        , ztimestamp timestamp NOT NULL
        );

INSERT INTO zaction(id, zcomment, ztimestamp) VALUES
 (   0110,      'random comment', '2017-04-27 12:00:00' )
,(   0117,      'text pattern 1', '2017-04-27 12:10:00' )
,(   0129,      'RANDOM COMMENT', '2017-04-27 12:20:00' )
,(   0130,      'text pattern 2', '2017-04-27 12:30:00' )
,(   0136,      'random comment', '2017-04-27 12:40:00' )
        --
,(   1110,      'random comment', '2017-04-27 12:00:00' )
,(   1117,      'text pattern 1', '2017-04-27 12:10:00' )
,(   1123,      'RANDOM COMMENT', '2017-04-27 12:20:00' )
,(   1129,      'RANDOM CONTENT', '2017-04-27 12:20:00' )
,(   1130,      'text pattern 2', '2017-04-27 12:30:00' )
,(   1136,      'random comment', '2017-04-27 12:40:00' )
        --
        ;

VACUUM ANALYZE zaction;


-- SELECT * FROM zaction;

EXPLAIN
WITH z1 AS (
        SELECT za.id
        , CASE WHEN zcomment ilike '%text pattern 1' THEN 1
             WHEN zcomment ilike '%text pattern 2' THEN -1
             ELSE 0 END AS dir
        FROM zaction za
        )
, z2 AS (
        SELECT z1.id, z1.dir
        , SUM(z1.dir) OVER (ORDER BY z1.id) AS yesno
        FROM z1
        )
SELECT za.*
FROM zaction za
JOIN z2 ON z2.id = za.id AND z2.yesno > 0 AND z2.dir = 0
        ;
```

---

Slightly modified version, which attempts to **keep the CTE(s) small**:

---

```
-- EXPLAIN
WITH z1 AS (
        SELECT za.id
        , CASE WHEN zcomment ilike '%text pattern 1' THEN 1
             WHEN zcomment ilike '%text pattern 2' THEN -1
             ELSE 0 END AS dir
        FROM zaction za
        WHERE zcomment ilike '%text pattern %'  -- <<== preselection to keep the CTE small
        )
SELECT za.*
FROM zaction za
JOIN (                                          -- <<== Join with subquery to give the optimiser some freedom
        SELECT za.id, z1.dir
        , SUM(z1.dir) OVER (ORDER BY za.id) AS yesno
        FROM zaction za
        LEFT JOIN z1 ON z1.id = za.id           -- <<== remerge with original set, whicha coulduse an index
        ) z2 ON z2.id = za.id AND z2.yesno > 0 AND z2.dir IS DISTINCT FROM 1
        ;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for posting these answers, I will be testing it out now on the database and post back shortly.

Comment: Remember: these queries will not be fast, the leading wildcard in `ilike '% xyz %'` is a nightmare.

Comment: Hi, so I've had a bit of time to mess about with this. Unfortunately  it's not giving me the result set expected. I seem to getting all the ids from the table inbetween the first instance of text pattern 1 and last instance of text pattern 2. What I was hoping to get was a collection of accounts where text pattern 1 and text pattern 2 occurred, and more specifically the actions inbetween those patterns for those said accounts. Currently I'm getting loads of accounts where this did not occur as it's showing me every action inbetween including accounts where these comments did not occur.

Comment: I hope I have explained this correctly, it's a bit of a tough one to explain. Perhaps the data set I sent was oversimplified, as it did not include accounts where this pattern did not occur, and I'd like to have those excluded although there were none to exclude in my example data set. Any ideas on how to get this working as intended would be much appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: Well,this solution *assumes* that the records are properly ordered (every start pattern has **exactly one** matching stop pattern, and that they do not *nest*)

Comment: I understand, unfortunately I can confirm this is not the case with the table. There will be some accounts where text pattern 1 occurs without text pattern 2 and visa versa. Apologies should have also mentioned that in the original question.

Comment: Then, probably you are doomed to use a cursor-driven state machine which emits {start,stop} -id pairs, but  only if these are not too far apart.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get the correct results with the following quey:

Comment: select ht.accountid
        ,string_agg(ht.id::TEXT, ', ') as actions_ids
        ,string_agg(ht.comment, ', ') as comments
    from historic_table ht 
   where ht.id > (select MAX(ht1.id) from historic_table ht1 where ht1.accountid = ht.accountid and ht1.comment ilike '%comment pattern 1%')
     and ht.id < (select MAX(ht2.id) from historic_table ht2 where ht2.accountid = ht.accountid and ht2.comment ilike '%comment pattern 2%')
group by ht.accountid
order by 1

Comment: Only thing is I had to settle on the format of the output by using string_agg. I didn't really want the output to be like this but I guess it's something I could try to work with.

Comment: I guess I'll post it as an answer as there could be some other poor sole pulling their hair out somewhere in some equally awkward database who might be able to make use of it! Just wanted to say thanks again for all your input, I would never have thought to code a solution in the way you proposed and as a consequence have learnt something new along the way.